# How to make malloc to a struct inside of another struct?

Tags: c, struct, malloc

In the first `.h` file, i have this struct:

```
typedef struct system
{
    char* name;
    DArray Info;
} *System;
```

And in the `.c` file I have this function:

```
System createSystem(char *name){
    if (!name){
        return NULL;
    }
    System newSystem=malloc(sizeof(*newSystem));
    if (!newSystem){
        return NULL;
    }
    newSystem->name=malloc(sizeof(strlen(name)+1));
    if (!newSystem->name){
       free(newSystem);
       return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(newSystem->name,name);
    newSystem->Info=malloc(sizeof *(newSystem->Info));
        if (!newSystem->Info){
            free(newSystem->name);
            free(newSystem);
            return NULL;
        }
        newSystem->Info->x=0;
        newSystem->Info->elements=NULL;
    return newSystem;
}
```

In another `.h` file I have the `struct dArray`:

```
typedef struct dArray
{
   int x;
    Element *elements;
} *DArray;
```

where `Element` could be of any type.

However, the function always stops working in Eclipse and I get the error

> hw stopped working

I know that the problem is in this line:

```
 newSystem->Info=malloc(sizeof(*newSystem->Info));
```

but I don't understand why this is a problem as I am trying to malloc to the `struct DArray` in a regular way!

I have been using this test in the main file:

```
int main() {
sys=createSystem("ss1");
if (sys) {
printf ("ok");
return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @coderredoc Actually, those parentheses are not needed (but are harmless).

Comment: Do not disguise pointer nature via `typedef`s.  It is much more confusing than helpful.

Comment: i did this and it didn't affect anything ..

Comment: but when i try to debbug the code it didn't dubbug beacause the dibugger stops in the middle of the leading process !

Comment: How do you know that the problem is related to the line you have called out?

Comment: i will post just a sec

Comment: becauuse when i deleate the line everything works fine

Comment: That's not a reliable test, @mamama, for several reasons.  And it furthermore seems highly unlikely that you could delete just that line and get everything working fine, for any plausible definition of "everything".  If that were really the case then deleting the line would be a solution to the problem.

Comment: true but the debugger didn;t work so i had no other choice .. i posted the full code

Comment: Either `malloc()` returns `NULL`, and the following segfault kills you, or you are experiencing undefined behavior somewhere else (something overwrites the book-keeping data that `malloc()` keeps internally). Try assigning the result of `malloc()` to a pointer variable first, and check whether the result is `NULL` to disambiguate.

Comment: ok i will do that now

Comment: ok apreantly if i add any malloc the code stops ...

Comment: The code as posted does not exhibit any problems.  The issue is probably in a related piece of code you haven't posted.  Try running your code through [valgrind](http://valgrind.org).  If you're running outside the bounds of allocated memory, it will tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System createSystem(char *name){
    if (!name){
        return NULL;
    }
    System newSystem=malloc(sizeof *newSystem);
    if (!newSystem){
        return NULL;
    }
    newSystem->name=malloc(sizeof *newSystem->name * (strlen(name)+1)); // <-- change here.
    if (!newSystem->name){
       free(newSystem);
       return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(newSystem->name,name);
    newSystem->Info=malloc(sizeof *newSystem->Info);
        if (!newSystem->Info){
            free(newSystem->name);
            free(newSystem);
            return NULL;
        }
        newSystem->Info->x=0;
        newSystem->Info->elements=NULL;
    return newSystem;
}
```

In case you are copying the string to dynamically allocated memory, it(`malloc`) basically allocate `sizeof (strlen(str)+1)` bytes of memory. And that will be nothing but `sizeof` operator applied to `size_t` which is unlikely to hold a characters string. (5 characters in my machine). 
(why `size_t`? Because the function strlen has a signature `size_t strlen(const char *s);`)

Also in my system `sizeof size_t` is 4 bytes. So basically you are allocating 5 bytes. That means the string will consists of 5 characters including the nul terminating character.

Anything more than length more comes like `"ABCDED"`, you are writing out of the memory you allocated causing an illegal memory access - and this has undefined behavior. In your case it simply stops.

To add more clarification, in your case I guess when you are entering the string you are passing something more than length `4`. But if you pass the string `"ss1"` then this will work.

`newSystem->name=malloc(sizeof *newSystem->name * (strlen(name)+1));` can be more clearly written as `newSystem->name=malloc(strlen(name)+1);`. As `sizeof char` is `1` byte we have avoided it.

You may later try to look up [`strdup`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html) function which is not part of ISO standard.

Comment: the struct itself i didn't wrote they were giving to us and they are suposed to work .. but  why in this line :"System* newSystem=malloc(sizeof(*newSystem));" i should add * , i mean System is already a pointer to the struct ..

Comment: You don't need to multiply by `sizeof *newSystem->name` as that is `sizeof(char)` which is always 1.  Its generally clearer to just use `malloc(strlen(name)+1)`, or even better `strdup(name)`.

Comment: @ChrisDodd.: You are right that `sizeof(char)` is one but it just goes with the habit to do it. But yes `malloc(strlen(name)+1)` is clearer. It reminded me of `strdup` but I didnt mention as it is not part of ISO C standard

Comment: this actually worked finally !! thank you so much for explainig this in such a good way :)

Answer (score 0):

below statement are not correct:-

`System newSystem=malloc(sizeof(*newSystem));` it should be System `newSystem=malloc(sizeof(struct system));`

and `newSystem->Info=malloc(sizeof *(newSystem->Info));` is `newSystem->Info` is a pointer? if pointer it should be  `newSystem->Info=malloc(sizeof(DArray));`

Comment: mmm i still get the same errror

Comment: put some printf statement in your code if you don't know how to debug. like printf("1\n"); printf("2\n"); etc in your code and check where it is breaking.

Comment: @Abhijit.: `System` is `struct system*`

Comment: @coderredoc, yes but he is using typedef so you can use both.

Comment: @Abhijit.: Your first statement is allocating a pointer variable's size of memory...not `struct system`

Comment: You said it should ne `System newSystem=malloc(sizeof(System));`...here we are not allocating memory for `struct system`. but we are allocating for `struct system*`

Comment: @coderredoc, true good catch. I did not check it was declared like that.

Answer (score 0):

Also, the following is not at all what you are after:
newSystem->name=malloc(sizeof(strlen(name)+1));

That is going to malloc() a buffer of (at minimum) sizeof(size_t) not a buffer capable of holding strlen(name)+1 bytes -- size_t is the return type of strlen and that is what the sizeof is being applied to.